# Combine two database columns as one array value php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that I am creating from a MySql database and encoding in json.

```
$data_array = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         $data_array[$row['city']] = $row['state']; 
}

 echo json_encode($data_array);
```

As expected, it is outputting this:

```
{"DALLAS":"WV","DALLAS CENTER":"IA","DALLAS CITY":"IL","DALLASTOWN":"PA","LAKE DALLAS":"TX"}
```

I need the json data to look like this:

```
{"DALLAS, WV","DALLAS CENTER, IA","DALLAS CITY, IL","DALLASTOWN, PA","LAKE DALLAS, TX"}
```

I can't seem to find the correct answer to this anywhere on Stack Overflow, so I apologize in advance if this is a repeat question. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this, as a key-value pair

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $data_array[$row['city']] = $row['state']; 
}
```

Generate it like this

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $data_array[] = $row['city'].",".$row['state']; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're currently using the following to build your array:

```
$data_array[$row['city']] = $row['state'];
```

This will cause the json to be `'city': 'state'`.

Try changing this to the format you want instead:

```
$data_array[] = $row['city'] . ', ' . $row['state'];
```

Now, you should have json the way you want with `'city, state'`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
$data_array[] = $row['city'] . "," . $row['state'];
```

PHP_DOC on mysql_*

> Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:

Comment: Did you mean to include additional information for the alternatives to the mysql_* comment?